# MapServer - How to display only X characters of annotation LABEL (text\string) based on [field]

Tags: labeling, mapserver, expression

In MapServer how\where do you use an expression to force a label to 5 characters to appear as annotation\labels

Comment: Do you want to display only the first five characters of a string as a label? What have you tried so far? An extract of your mapfile would help.